# google-oauth-java-client fails with twitch

Tags: java, google-oauth, google-oauth-java-client

basically cross from https://discuss.dev.twitch.tv/t/using-google-oauth-client-java-fails-to-execute-token-request/24191
the exception I get is this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: key scope
    at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parseValue(JsonParser.java:902)
    at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parse(JsonParser.java:362)
    at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parse(JsonParser.java:337)
    at com.google.api.client.json.JsonObjectParser.parseAndClose(JsonObjectParser.java:79)
    at com.google.api.client.json.JsonObjectParser.parseAndClose(JsonObjectParser.java:73)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponse.parseAs(HttpResponse.java:444)
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest.execute(TokenRequest.java:346)
    at de.cryptearth.oauth.Main.main(Main.java:67)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: key scope, field private java.lang.String com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponse.scope
    at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parseValue(JsonParser.java:902)
    at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parse(JsonParser.java:453)
    at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parseValue(JsonParser.java:789)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: expected collection or array type but got class java.lang.String
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:164)
    at com.google.api.client.util.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:67)
    at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parseValue(JsonParser.java:726)
    ... 9 more
```

Any Idea what might could be the issue here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, tried several OAuth libs linked on oaut.net but got none to work, so I ended up in doing it low-level with URLConnection and RegEx parsing.
Side-note: I also tried the other libs on YouTube, but only could Googles own implementation to work on it.
~closed